# Using variables from json - Google play games quests

Tags: c#, android, json, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have added Google play games services to my android app in Unity3d. I am trying to add quests, but am having issues claiming the reward. In the developer console, i have uploaded this reward data file:

{
    "Coins" : 10
}

In Unity, I am accessing this by using

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(quest.Milestone.CompletionRewardData)
```

Which returns: { "Coins" : 10 }

My question is, how do i then turn the variable coins into a c# variable for use in my app?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use NewtonSoft JSON library for parsing json data. It is very easy to use for parsing complex data. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: I'm confused. Could you maybe write a bit of code showing how to do it? All i need to get is the value of coins. Thanks @Sandy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using [JSONObject](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710) in Unity to create and parse JSON, it's quite easy to use.

```
string reward = "{ \"Coins\" : 10 }";

JSONObject rewardJSON = new JSONObject(reward);
int coins = int.Parse(rewardJSON.GetField("Coins").ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to solve this for days and my brain was melting! Thanks you :) @david145